# How to HTTP/2 on CentOS 7 - PHP7 - Apache

Tags: apache, centos7, php-7, http2

After some research I cannot find answer for:
How to **update** Apache/httpd to newest version to use HTTP/2 protocol on my VPS.
I'm using PHP7 & my server based on Apache - CentOS 7.

No package updates on CentOS defaults repo.

```
[root@vps270238 ~]# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Nov 19 2015 21:43:13
```

I really want to keep my actual settings and Virtual Hosts.

Comment: Damian welcome to SO. This isn't really a programming question. you should check out the other stack exchange sites that may be able to help you more than the folks here. maybe http://serverfault.com/ or http://superuser.com/

Comment: Thank you for answer, I will try on serverfault then. Cheers